# python csv file with several columns

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Hello i want to create a csv file in python with the standard library csv.
My Code:

```
csv_columns = ['receiptNr','category','date','allvalue', 'quantity', 'value']
dict_data = {'receiptNr': 293293, 'category': 'Sbudget' ,'date': '29.11.2020' ,'allvalue': '2.70' , 'quantity': '2 STK' , 'value': '1.35'}

csv_file = r"C:\Maturaprojekt\table.csv"


try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns, lineterminator = '\n')  
        writer.writeheader()       
        writer.writerow(dict_data)
        
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

the output is:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/734AN.png)

but i want to have:
[wantedfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRq3k.png)

raw text data:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD7XM.png)

Comment: You're showing us screenshots from a spreadsheet program, but that hides the actual CSV data. Please show us the CSV data in text form instead.

Comment: now i have added the output when i open it with the editor.

Comment: the fields have other names but the principle is the same.   thx for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's problem of delimiter.

The delimiter used in your `csv` file is probably not the same delimiter used in your spreadsheet program.

You can add a delimiter parameter to csv.DictWriter to change the delimiter of your `csv` file if you want, like this:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=';', fieldnames=csv_columns, lineterminator = '\n')
```

Or you could change the `csv file` delimiter chosen in your spreadsheet program.

As @Chris commented, you're showing us screenshots from a spreadsheet program, you will have to select the right delimiter in your spreadsheet program (usually when you open the csv file).

In short: the default delimiter used by `csv.DictWriter` is not the same that is used in your spreadsheet program.

How you could change the delimiter (separator) used by your spreadshet program depends on the spreadsheet program you use.
You could go to your favorite search engine and search for something like this:
`csv file change separator libreoffice`, or `csv file change separator excel`, or `csv file change delimiter excel`, etc.

Comment: The `csv` module defaults to a comma as its delimiter, and every spreadsheet program I've ever used can import data that's comma separated. It's likely that _no_ code changes are necessary. OP just needs to open the file properly.

Comment: I agree, I didn't say that his spreadsheet program could not import data that's comma separated. I said that it's possible that the delimiter chosen in his spreadsheet program is not the same as in his ```csv``` file.

Comment: Fair, but opening the file properly seems like a much better solution than actually changing the exported data.

Comment: the method of @Rivers helped me out and now the file seems to be how i like it. :) Thx for your help Rivers! but i would like to hear the solution from Chris aswell maybe it also works?